# JUMP_FORWARD or JUMP_ABSOLUTE with IF statement ? Python 2.5

Tags: python, if-statement, bytecode

I have been using '[dis](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html)' module in order to re-write some compiled script (.pyc). I understand the difference between JUMP_FORWARD and JUMP_ABSOLUTE. To my knowledge an IF statement will be closed by a JUMP_FORWARD:

```
>>> def f():
        if a:
                print ''
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
              3 JUMP_IF_FALSE            9 (to 15)
              6 POP_TOP             

  3           7 LOAD_CONST               1 ('')
             10 PRINT_ITEM          
             11 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             12 JUMP_FORWARD             1 (to 16)
        >>   15 POP_TOP             
        >>   16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

And the JUMP_ABSOLUTE will appear if the IF statement is at the end of another loop. For instance:

```
>>> def f1():
    if a:
        if b:
            print ''
>>> dis(f1)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
              3 JUMP_IF_FALSE           20 (to 26)
              6 POP_TOP             

  3           7 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (b)
             10 JUMP_IF_FALSE            9 (to 22)
             13 POP_TOP             

  4          14 LOAD_CONST               1 ('')
             17 PRINT_ITEM          
             18 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           27
        >>   22 POP_TOP             
             23 JUMP_FORWARD             1 (to 27)
        >>   26 POP_TOP             
        >>   27 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             30 RETURN_VALUE
```

From the Bytecode I am reading to write back the code, there is a JUMP_ABSOLUTE that surprises me:

```
121         228 LOAD_FAST               11 (a)
            231 LOAD_CONST               9 (100)
            234 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
            237 JUMP_IF_FALSE           23 (to 263)
            240 POP_TOP             
            241 LOAD_FAST               11 (b)
            244 LOAD_CONST              11 (10)
            247 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
            250 JUMP_IF_FALSE           10 (to 263)
            253 POP_TOP             

122         254 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
            257 STORE_FAST               4 (ok)
            260 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           27
        >>  263 POP_TOP
```

I would think the code is the following:

```
if a<100 and b>10:
            ok=1
```

but it provokes a JUMP_FORWARD and not a JUMP_ABSOLUTE. I know it is not a WHILE loop, nor a FOR statement because they both create a SETUP_LOOP line in the Bytecode.

My question is: what am I missing ? why do I get a FORWARD instead of ABSOLUTE jump ?

EDIT: The absolute jump to index 27 points to the beginning of a (WHILE?) loop in which these two lines 121 and 122 belong to:

```
106          24 SETUP_LOOP             297 (to 324)
        >>   27 LOAD_FAST                4 (ok)
             30 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             33 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             36 JUMP_IF_FALSE          283 (to 322)
             39 POP_TOP
```

There is an IF-statement before and another one after these lines. Here is the code before, with the same JUMP_ABSOLUTE closing the statement.

```
115         170 LOAD_FAST                3 (q)
            173 LOAD_CONST              10 (1)
            176 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
            179 JUMP_IF_FALSE           45 (to 227)
            182 POP_TOP             
            183 LOAD_FAST               11 (z)
            186 LOAD_CONST              11 (10)
            189 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
            192 JUMP_IF_FALSE           32 (to 227)
            195 POP_TOP             

116         196 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
            199 STORE_FAST               4 (ok)

117         202 LOAD_FAST                5 (u)
            205 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
            208 BINARY_ADD          
            209 STORE_FAST               5 (u)

118         212 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
            215 STORE_FAST               3 (k)

119         218 LOAD_CONST               3 (10)
            221 STORE_FAST               6 (dv)
            224 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           27
        >>  227 POP_TOP
```

The JUMP_FORWARD says "go to the next line" and the JUMP_ABSOLUTE says "go back to the beginning of the WHILE loop". Problem is I don't know how to replicate a code that would give the same bytecode as above.

Thank you !

Comment: Was your `.pyc` created with the same version of Python as you are using now? Which version is that?

Comment: I am quite sure it was created with Python 2.5, same I am using right now. I checked the magic number.

Comment: You mentioned that you know this is not a loop. But JUMP_ABSOLUTE 27 indicates that the jump is taking you quite a long way back in the code. Did you look as far back as the opcode with index 27 to see what it was actually jumping back to, to make sure this is not a loop? It might be beneficial to include more disassembled code to give the complete picture, especially so that it is possible to see where the jump goes to.

Comment: The IF statement is actually inside a WHILE loop and the absolute jump points to its initialization, I added more code in the post. Thank you @ReinierTorenbeek for your time

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your changes, but this is a tedious process and I wonder what your final goal is. Maybe you should try [uncompyle](https://github.com/Mysterie/uncompyle2)? It is " A Python 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 byte-code decompiler, written in Python 2.7". I have not tried it myself but would be interested in your experience.

Comment: you just made my day ! I installed 2.7 and this module, ran it and the code just popped out. Turns out `else` statements do not appear on bytecode, so you can't tell if a line is empty or if it contains an `else` statement. Secondly you also cannot tell the difference between an `if` and `elif`, unless you realize `elif` provokes absolute jumps just like in this situation. I'll update my original post tomorrow and will show you the code. Thank you again for contributing to this question.

Comment: OK, that is good to read. I added the `uncompyle2` suggestion to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took the challenge and with your help was able to reproduce your situation (or something very similar) using the following (nonsense) function:

```
>>> def f():
...    while ok==0:
...      if q<1 and z>10:
...        ok=0
...        u=u+1
...        k=0
...        dv=10
...      elif a<100 and b>10:
...        ok=1
...
>>> dis(f)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP             112 (to 115)
        >>    3 LOAD_FAST                0 (ok)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              9 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             12 JUMP_IF_FALSE           98 (to 113)
             15 POP_TOP

  3          16 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (q)
             19 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             22 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             25 JUMP_IF_FALSE           45 (to 73)
             28 POP_TOP
             29 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (z)
             32 LOAD_CONST               3 (10)
             35 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             38 JUMP_IF_FALSE           32 (to 73)
             41 POP_TOP

  4          42 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             45 STORE_FAST               0 (ok)

  5          48 LOAD_FAST                1 (u)
             51 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             54 BINARY_ADD
             55 STORE_FAST               1 (u)

  6          58 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             61 STORE_FAST               2 (k)

  7          64 LOAD_CONST               3 (10)
             67 STORE_FAST               3 (dv)
             70 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   73 POP_TOP

  8          74 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (a)
             77 LOAD_CONST               4 (100)
             80 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             83 JUMP_IF_FALSE           23 (to 109)
             86 POP_TOP
             87 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (b)
             90 LOAD_CONST               3 (10)
             93 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             96 JUMP_IF_FALSE           10 (to 109)
             99 POP_TOP

  9         100 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
            103 STORE_FAST               0 (ok)
            106 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>  109 POP_TOP
            110 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>  113 POP_TOP
            114 POP_BLOCK
        >>  115 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            118 RETURN_VALUE
```

Lines 8 and 11 have the `JUMP_ABSOLUTE` that you were asking for. Slight differences like `LOAD_GLOBAL` versus `LOAD_FAST` are caused by the scope of the variables.

Note that I had to switch to Python 2.5 to reproduce this. Newer versions produce different results.

If `continue` does not seem to be applicable to your situation, I suggest you do some research in the source code of Python and look for `ADDOP_JABS` in [`Python/compile.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/80b1dc3b3231/Python/compile.c) to find out in what other cases an absolute jump is inserted.

If your goal is to "just" decompile this `.pyc`, then you should try [`uncompyle2`](https://github.com/Mysterie/uncompyle2), which describes itself as "A Python 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 byte-code decompiler, written in Python 2.7"

Comment: I haven't thought about using `continue`, it is almost the solution ! Problem is it does not remove the `JUMP_FORWARD` caused by the IF statement, it adds an absolute jump. You still have the `JUMP_FORWARD` on line 8 pointing to the next line.

Comment: Although you already accepted the answer (thanks) I updated the answer and inserted your own `elif` suggestion for future reference.